# X-Path expression to pull data from a table row

Tags: xpath, html-table

I am new to Xpath. I tried to write an xpath expression which returns all the valid elements in a above table row (Marked as 'Required').

XPath Used:

`.//*[@id='reportListItemID0']/td[not(@width) and child::node()] | .//*[@id='reportListItemID0']/td[not(@width) and not(child::node())]`

```
<tr style="" class="deatilRow" id="reportListItemID0" nowrap="">
    <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>04/04/2013</td><!----------------------------Required-->
    <td width="3px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Morkel, Rashid</td><!------------------------Required-->
    <td width="3px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>100668041</td><!-----------------------------Required-->
    <td width="3px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td><!--------------------------------------Required-->
    <td width="3px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:makePost(somelink);" class="dynamicLinks">XA0404181004596</a><!--Required-->
    </td>
    <td width="3px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$31.00</td><!--------------------------------Required-->
    <td width="3px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <span class="workedYesNoColor">N</span><!----Required-->
    </td>
    <td width="3px" colspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

The X-Path used returns the below listed elements:

```
<td>04/04/2013</td>
<td>Morkel, Rashid</td>
<td>100668041</td>
<td></td>
<td> <a href="javascript:..." class="dynamicLinks">XA0404181004596</a> </td>
<td>$31.00</td>
<td> <span class="workedYesNoColor">N</span> </td>
```

But the Expected Result is as below: (The leaf nodes are only required and not the 'td')

```
<td>04/04/2013</td>
<td>Morkel, Rashid</td>
<td>100668041</td>
<td></td>
<a href="javascript:..." class="dynamicLinks">XA0404181004596</a>
<td>$31.00</td>
<span class="workedYesNoColor">N</span>
```

Important Note: The position of the 'td' with tags 'a' and 'span' can vary. They are not present at the 5th and 6th position consistently.

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: That's not easy, if possible, to accomplish with only XPath, since `text()` is still a `node()`. If you're already using XPath, you should already have a DOM interpreter at hand, so it's better to use DOM to fetch the "leaf" node if exists.

Comment: @Passerby Today I have completed my coding using DOM interpreter to fetch the leaf nodes. Still I would like to know if it's possible via xpath alone. It would reduce the lines of coding required.

Comment: I doubt that. `text()` is a `node()`, so you can't use condition like `has node`; in `\n\t<element>...`, `\n\t` is a `text()`, so condition like `count node` could hardly help too. You can use XPath to query `<td>`s, and then use DOM to fetch leaf in it.